# Find the sum of the infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin nx^2}{1+n^3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin nx^2}{1+n^3}=?$

Writing down few elements didn't help me. I also tried to used integral test but didn't work as well. How should I proceed? Help me out.

**One side question:** If there exists a closed form, does the sum defines a continuously differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: But that doesn't give the value, which seems to be what OP is asking for.

Comment: Well it obviously converges. But it converges to an expression involving the hypergeometric function. Is that what you want?

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you want to find the sum, or just want to know whether the series converges?

Comment: Is that numerator $\sin (nx^2)$? and I don't think there is a specific value in closed form using elementary functions for that.

Comment: Yes I want the sum. Convergence part I know.

Comment: Numerator is like that. But I don't know is there any closed form for this or not.

Comment: @Macavity Good point. I was assuming it was $\sin(nx^2)$. The answer still involves hypergeometric functions if it is $(\sin(nx))^2$, but we need to be sure which it is.

Comment: Wow I didn't realize that the sum looks this big.

Comment: @Macavity, Why is there a Hypergeometric function inside another hypergeometric function? This is probably incorrectly edited Mathematica notation, right?

Comment: @Macavity: I think YuriyS is right.

Comment: OK, here is unedited from Mathematica - looks the same to me: $$\frac{\left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{3}-i\right) \left(\, _4F_3\left(1,1,-1+\sqrt[3]{-1},-1-(-1)^{2/3};2,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2};e^{-i x^2}\right)-\, _4F_3\left(1,1,-1+\sqrt[3]{-1},-1-(-1)^{2/3};2,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2};e^{i x^2}\right)\right)}{8 \left(\sqrt[3]{-1}-1\right) \left(1+(-1)^{2/3}\right)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maple expresses it as
$$\eqalign{-\frac{i}{12}&{{\rm e}^{-i{x}^{2}}} \left( 1+i\sqrt {3} \right) {\it LerchPhi}
 \left( {{\rm e}^{-i{x}^{2}}},1,1/2-i/2\sqrt {3} \right)\cr
 +\frac{i}{12}&{{\rm e}
^{-i{x}^{2}}} \left( -1+i\sqrt {3} \right) {\it LerchPhi} \left( {
{\rm e}^{-i{x}^{2}}},1,1/2+i/2\sqrt {3} \right)\cr +\frac{i}{12}&{{\rm e}^{i{x}^{2
}}} \left( 1+i\sqrt {3} \right) {\it LerchPhi} \left( {{\rm e}^{i{x}^{
2}}},1,1/2-i/2\sqrt {3} \right)\cr -\frac{i}{12}&{{\rm e}^{i{x}^{2}}} \left( -1+i
\sqrt {3} \right) {\it LerchPhi} \left( {{\rm e}^{i{x}^{2}}},1,1/2+i/2
\sqrt {3} \right)\cr -\frac{i}{6}& \left( {{\rm e}^{i{x}^{2}}}\ln  \left( 1-{
{\rm e}^{-i{x}^{2}}} \right) -{{\rm e}^{-i{x}^{2}}}\ln  \left( -{
{\rm e}^{i{x}^{2}}}+1 \right)  \right) }
$$

Comment: Ok can you give me the answer for the other question that I've written as "one side question"?

Comment: Yes, this is continuously differentiable, and its derivative is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2nx \sin(nx^2)/(1+n^3)$, which also converges.